# Regex for check string check that does not contain \ > <

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a regular expression to check if the string contains only digits, alphabets and other symbols except `\ > <`. I am able to create for digits and alphabets. I have tried with `[^\<>]` to check if string doesn't contain  `\ > <` special characters.

But it  did't work. Can someone please suggest how it an be done.

Edit:

Might be a simple question, but I am just starting with regx.

Comment: What does 'didn't work' mean? How did you use that regex?

Comment: `[^\\<>]` seems ok for me. What doesn't work?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and then explain what didn't work.  Give us specific examples.

Comment: I am using Pattern and Matcher in java code . I am trying to validate a string

Comment: Try escaping the \ as \\. \ is a special character.

Comment: Why would you not let the user use those characters in a password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\` is a special character in regex, even inside of a character class. If you want to use it as literal character, you have to escape it, so the regex would be

```
[^\\<>]
```

if you use it in Java you have to escape additionally for the string level, so it would appear as:

```
String regex = "[^\\\\<>]";
```

Comment: How about doing a simple match for those characters instead (\<>)

Comment: Just a distinction - Regex level is regex, there is no reason to escape anything unless its intended as a literal. Otherwise, the OP might do things like [\\\\s] on the string level, that translates to [\\s] on the regex level.

Comment: A good way to avoid ambiguity by showing the regex as it would appear in the source code where it's used.  So in Perl it would be `/[^\\<>]/`, and in Java, `"[^\\\\<>]"`

Comment: @sln I have clarified the answer by using Alan Moores suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Matching against `[^\<>]` will succeed if the string contains *even one character* which is not a backslash or angle bracket. If you wish it to succeed only when *no* character in the string is one of the forbidden ones, use

```
^[^\\<>]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
^[^\\<>]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

e.g.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("^[^\\\\<>]*$");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher("Hello World!").matches()
    );  // prints "true"
    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher("<script ...></script>").matches()
    );  // prints "false"
}
```

Comment: That's a neat visualization! How was that made?

Comment: See http://www.debuggex.com/. It does not work with all regexes (I think only those that are compatible with JavaScript), for example `(?<=X)` don't works.

Comment: Hey there, I'm the founder of Debuggex. You can change the regex flavor that you're working with in the top right (currently we support js, python, and pcre). We're working on making this more intuitive.